Get monetization status of a post through facebook API
Is there a way to get the status of a post through the Facebook API, specifically whether monetization is enabled or if it has been restricted due to violations of Facebook's monetization policies or copyright issues?
I searched through the Facebook API documentation, including sections on post insights, but couldn't find any clear reference to retrieving the monetization status.
